# show flash using original canvas size dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a generalized media player web app that I wish to be able to use flash in. The client uploads the flash to a particular directory, and a webpage is produced automatically that houses that flash file. The output of this process currently looks something like this:

`<OBJECT id="flashContent" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">

<PARAM value="always" name="allowScriptAccess" />

<PARAM value="#FFFFFF" name="bgcolor" />

<PARAM value="opaque" name="wmode" />

<PARAM value="high" name="quality" />

<PARAM value="test.swf" name="movie" />

</OBJECT>`

I am trying to get the flash to display using the original canvas size (540 x 400 by default) but every time I load this in chrome I get 300 x 150 and in IE the box is square.

Any idea how to get it to render using the flash canvas size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this.  You'll either have to know the dimensions ahead of time and set them in the embed, or modify the SWF to expose JavaScript callbacks (with [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)) and call those.

Answer (score 0):

forget about raw embedding, use js wrapper:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

snippet is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "540", "400", "9.0.0","expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

Comment: right, so I'm actually doing something like this. The problem is I don't know the height and width of the flash I'm loading. I need to either query the flash for its size, or just let it default to the right size.

Comment: you can call via ExternalInterface the swf object and update the sizes after in js